# Solr 6.0.1 warning - IndexFetcher - Exception while updating statistics AccessDeniedException

Tags: exception, solr, solr6

Running Solr 6.0.1, and I am getting this warning in the logs sporadically.  The times it's happened in the last few hours are 1:43:27, 1:53:26, 2:11:06, 2:17:26, 2:21:46, 2:22:26, and here's the full error...

> Time: 8/11/2016, 2:27:26 PM
>
> Level: WARN true
>
> Logger: IndexFetcher
>
> Message: Exception while updating statistics
>
> Details: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\solr-6.0.1\server\solr\MySolrCore\data\replication.properties
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(Unknown Source)
>       at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
>       at java.nio.file.Files.newOutputStream(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.(FSDirectory.java:408)
>       at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.(FSDirectory.java:404)
>       at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.createOutput(FSDirectory.java:253)
>       at org.apache.lucene.store.NRTCachingDirectory.createOutput(NRTCachingDirectory.java:157)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.IndexFetcher.logReplicationTimeAndConfFiles(IndexFetcher.java:688)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.IndexFetcher.fetchLatestIndex(IndexFetcher.java:500)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.IndexFetcher.fetchLatestIndex(IndexFetcher.java:270)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler.doFetch(ReplicationHandler.java:387)
>       at org.apache.solr.handler.ReplicationHandler.lambda$setupPolling$0(ReplicationHandler.java:1088)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

It's just a warning, but do you know why this is happening, and how I can prevent it?

I am also getting another warning that occurs twice when the core is started: Logger: IndexFetcher, Message: 'masterUrl' must be specified without the /replication suffix.  If I take off the /replication suffix in the config, then my replication does not work.  I am including this error because the file in the above warning is replication.properties, and both warnings refer to replicaiton, so they may or may not be related.  Eliminating both warnings would be ideal.  Thanks.